# Equilibrium Solutions - Seeing Algebraically why starting at an equilibrium point leads to a constant solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, steady-state

We define an **equilibrium point**  as a point **$\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb R^n$** such that for the dynamical system $ \frac{d\bf x}{dt}=\bf{F(x)}$ we have $\bf{F(a)}=\mathbf{0}$.

> **Claim:** A solution $\mathbf{x}(t)$ such that $\mathbf{x}(0)=\mathbf a$ is just the constant function $\mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{a}$.

I've been trying to show myself why this is true algebraically. Intuitively, it makes sense that if you start at a point where there is no tendency to change, then your solution willl just be a constant at that equilibrium point. However I'm not sure how to "show" this?

Can someone please explain why this is true? (I tried to go for an explanation like "since the derivative is zero, then the solution must be a constant" - but this doesn't make sense to be since the derivative is only zero at **one** point, how can we infer a constant solution (without intuition) only given the initial condition?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For this kind of differential equation, and minimum regularity requirements on $F$ (locally Lipschitz), there is a unique solution to the equation given the initial conditions. The constant function is such a solution, so it is the one.

Comment: @Mindlack Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. Is the claim not true if the function $F$ is not Lipschitz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of dynamical systems you normally assume $F$ to be at least continuously differentiable and then Picard-Lindelöf gives you uniqueness of the solution. As the constant function is clearly a solution to the problem, it has to be the only one.

Of course, you are right: If $F$ is does not satisfy the conditions needed for Picard-Lindelöf (Lipschitz-continuity) then this is not true:

$$\dot{x} = \sqrt{\left|x\right|}$$
$$x(0) = 0$$

has two solutions: The constant function $x(t) = 0$ but also $x(t) =\frac{t²}{4}$

Comment: Precise, clear answer. Referenced results, provided a clear counterexample when the condition does not hold: Thank you!

Comment: Any other piecewise combination $x(t)=\frac14[\max(0,t-a)-\min(0,t+b)^2]$ with $a,b>0$ is also a solution, so you get "has more than two solutions".