# Initial value problem of $y'(x)=2\cdot\sqrt{|y(x)|}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I have a problem to solve this initial value problem of $y'(x)=2\cdot\sqrt{|y(x)|}$ with $y(0)=0$.

How to solve initial value problems in general is clear to me (integrate and determine the constant). However, I don't know how to deal with the $y(x)$. I think this is a special case of initial value problems with an infinite number of solutions?
How can I solve this problem?

(I cannot integrate $y(x)$ in the form in which the initial value problem is now presented, and how do I then determine the infinite solutions?).

Comment: Since $\lvert y \rvert = y$ for $y > 0$ and $\lvert y \rvert = -y$ for $y < 0$, break the problem into two cases. (You can reassemble the two solutions at the end, using absolute value if you like.)

Comment: @SammyBlack: But I have |y(x)| or does that correspond to |y| in the context?

Comment: Yeah, it's poor notation, but quite common. It's meant to emphasize the fact that $y$ depends on $x$, but the dependency really should be expressed with a different function name, like $y = f(x)$.

Comment: Your question was answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280533/equilibrium-solutions-seeing-algebraically-why-starting-at-an-equilibrium-poin?noredirect=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$ and $y\in[0,\infty)$.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2\sqrt{y}$$

$$\Rightarrow\sqrt{y}=x$$

But we have $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$

so we must have

$$y=\begin{cases} 
      0 & x\leq x_0 \\
      (x-x_0)^2 & x\geq x_0       
   \end{cases}$$

where $x_0$ is any real number.

So you do have infinite solutions here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation